# pass data from view controller to tabbarviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am segueing from a view controller to a tabbarcontroller and I want to pass data. I want to pass "sendAuthor" to the first view controller of the tabbarcontroller.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "FirstVC" {

  let vc = (segue.destination as? UITabBarController)?.viewControllers?.first as? CommentProfileViewController

    vc?.sendAuthor = sendAuthor!
    vc?.Username.text = sendAuthor!

        print(sendAuthor!)
    }



    }
```

In order to make sure I am getting the right thing, I included a print statement `print(sendAuthor!)` and I am getting the correct print statement. I also included a print statement in the destination view controller but the print statement returns nil

```
var sendAuthor: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
print(self.sendAuthor)

}
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan the vc itself

Comment: just before `let vc = `, add this: `print(type(of: (segue.destination as? UITabBarController)?.viewControllers?.first))` and let us know what it prints.

Comment: Do you hook segue destination to the tabBar itself or to the first Vc of it ,  Also are you sure that the first VC name is **CommentProfileViewController**

Comment: @vacawama it prints out Optional<UIViewController>

Comment: @Sh_Khan I hooked it to the tabbar itself

Comment: I think you forgot to set the viewController class in the storyboard for your first view Controller of your `UITabBarController`.  Set it to `CommentProfileViewController`.

Comment: @vacawama i did

Comment: OK, then try `print(type(of: (segue.destination as! UITabBarController)!.viewControllers!.first!))`

Comment: @vacawama it doesn't run, i get Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context

Comment: I had an extra `!`, although how you get that message I'm not sure.  Try this: `print(type(of: (segue.destination as! UITabBarController).viewControllers!.first!))`

Comment: @vacawama it prints out UINavigationController

Comment: Eureka!  There's your problem.  You need an extra step to get past the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: @vacawama how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VC is imbedded in a `UINavigationController`.  You need to take that into account as well:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "FirstVC" {
       guard let tabbar = segue.destination as? UITabBarController,
             let navcon = tabbar.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController,
             let vc = navcon.topViewController as? CommentProfileViewController
             else { return }

       vc.sendAuthor = sendAuthor!
       vc.Username.text = sendAuthor!

       print(sendAuthor!)
    }
}
```